# Screen of chars

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11

So its a class that lets you make a 'Screen' which is a n x n grid of chars. Your able to move a cursor by chosing the row and which column in the row and using that you can insert into into that place and change the char thats there.

```
#ifndef Screen_h
#define Screen_h

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string makeString(const int, const char);

class Screen
{
public:
    Screen() = default;
    Screen(int num, char chr) { setRows(num, chr); }

    void setRows(const int, const char); // Sets the rows and columns
    void display() const; // Outputs the rows and columns
    void moveCursor(int, int); // Lets user mover cursor but chosing the row and column
    void insert(const char chr); // Using the cursors location you can change a character
private: 
    void setDefaultCursor(); // Sets the cursor to the character in the first row
    std::string::iterator cursor; // The cursor
    std::vector<std::string> rows; // All the rows
};

// Member funtions

void Screen::setDefaultCursor() {
    auto row = rows.begin();
    cursor = row->begin();
}

void Screen::setRows(const int num, const char chr) {
    rows.clear();
    const std::string row = makeString(num, chr);
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt != num; ++cnt) {
        rows.push_back(row);
    }
    setDefaultCursor();
}

void Screen::display() const {
    for (const auto c : rows) {
        std::cout << c << '\n';
    }
}

void Screen::moveCursor(int AmmRow, int AmmAccross) {
    if (rows.size() < AmmRow || rows.begin()->size() < AmmAccross) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cursor move is too big");
    }
    auto row = (rows.begin() + --AmmRow);
    cursor = row->begin() + --AmmAccross;
}

void Screen::insert(const char chr) {
    *cursor = chr;
}

// Non member function but still related funtions

std::string makeString(const int length, const char chr) {
    std::string str;
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt != length; ++cnt) {
        str.push_back(chr);
    }
    return str;
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class looks quite good! There are some implementation details you can be more idiomatic with.

For `setDefaultCursor`, there is no need for a temporary variable:

```
void Screen::setDefaultCursor() 
{
    cursor = rows.front().begin();
}
```

Also, `makeString` is obsolete. There is already such a constructor for `std::string`. Similarly, there is such a constructor for `std::vector`. So we can improve on `setRows`:

```
void Screen::setRows(const int num, const char chr) 
{
    rows = std::vector<std::string>(num, std::string(num, chr));
    setDefaultCursor();
}
```

Let me also mention that in `moveCursor`, I think it's a bad habit to use statements that have side effects. Instead of saying e.g., "x += (--y)", just decrement y first, and then add it to x. This improves readability a lot.